# Find if there exist some combination of these digits that will be divisible by 8 or not

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

Let's say I am given some 100 digits and I have to find whether there can be any combination of these digits such that the number formed will be divisible by 8, how can I do that?

I know divisibility rule for 8 is that any number will be divisible by 8 if last 3 digits are divisible by 8.. But how to find that in a shuffled digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones digit has to be even, which will make the final number divisible by $2$.  If the ones digit is $2$ or $6$, the tens digit needs to be odd so the final number is divisible by $4$.  If the ones digit is $0,4,8$ the tens digit needs to be even.  Then pick the hundreds digit (you can find a similar rule) so the whole thing is divisible by $8$

Of course, if there is an $8$ in the pile, you can just pick that and stop.

Added: another approach is to make a list of all the multiples of $8$ from $000$ through $992$.  Then just look through you list of digits to see if you have any combination.  If you have $100$ digits, the odds you have any given one is quite high, so you won't have to look far.

Comment: Not a subset, we need to rearrange all the digits to find any such number that will be divisible by 8

Comment: If you find the last three digits as in the first paragraph, you can put the rest in front in any order you like.  That comes from the divisibility test you cited.  You just have to find a three digit combination to be the last three.

Comment: Since that is a programming question, how will I perform this action? There are like really many many possibilities..

Comment: I suggested you see if there are any suitable ones digits.  If not, report failure. If so, there are two classes as I show.  For each class, see if there is an appropriate tens digit.  Then for each class (how many are there now?) see if there is an appropriate hundreds digit. If so, report success.  If you need to return the number, once you have the last three digits,  the rest can go in any order.